# Looking for help in correcting the syntax error in my Verilog code

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

```
module HazardDetectionUnit(stall, Rs1, Rt1, Rt2, MemRead2, clk);
  input clk, MemRead2;
  input [4:0] Rs1, Rt1, Rt2;
  output reg [2:0] stall;
  always @(negedge clk) 
  begin
    if(MemRead2 & ((Rt2 = Rs1) | (Rt2 = Rt1)))  //Error has been detected in this line
      stall <= 3'b000;
    else
      stall <= 3'b111;
  end
endmodule
```

> ERROR: /nfs/home/s/s_ankith/HazardDetectionUnit_MIPS.v(7): near ")":
> Syntax error.  Assignment sub-exprs. are only allowed in SystemVerilog
> or PSL.

Answer (score 1):

You need `==` for testing equality:

```
if(MemRead2 & ((Rt2 == Rs1) | (Rt2 == Rt1)))
```